How to get lowercase and uppercase alphabet letters using C# regular expressions?
How to get lowercase and uppercase alphabet letters using C# regular expressions?
my code
string inputText = "afaUTE123567645gfhdDSFSD21312ASDFSAF21312sdafASasdfDF213asefd";
string pattern = @"(?'AlphabetLower'[a-z]+)|(?'AlphabetUpper'[A-Z]+)|(?'Alphabet'[a-zA-Z]+)|(?'Number'[0-9]+)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(inputText, pattern).Cast<Match>().OrderBy(s => s.Index);

my output is not work.
I want output :
enter image description here
*ps : In the future, I would also like to add Greek letter(lowercase, uppercase and mixed)

I'm confused about what exactly you want as the result of your code. In addition, do you need to use regex? There are other tools that might be more appropriate.

If you want all unicode alphabets (Greek, Cyrillic etc.) you can try using \p{Lu} instead of [A-Z], \p{Ll} instead of [a-z] and, finally, \p{L} instead of [A-Za-z]

It looks like you probably want to combine all the alphabet options together, separately from the numeric pieces. Something like this:
(?'AnyAlphabet'(?'AlphabetLower'[a-z]+)|(?'AlphabetUpper'[A-Z]+)|(?'Alphabet'[a-zA-Z]+))+|(?'Number'[0-9]+)

But depending on your actual use case, you could probably simplify this quite a bit, or use a parsing library like Sprache.

I suggest to use regex just to determine indexes at which you should break the string. Pattern for that is easy:
[a-z][^a-z]|[A-Z][^A-Z]|[0-9][^0-9]

Explanation:
[a-z][^a-z] - match lowercase followed by non-lowercase
| - alternation operator
[A-Z][^A-Z] - match uppercase followed by non-uppercase
[0-9][^0-9] - match digit followed by non-digit
This will give you all indexes at which you should slice your string. Then you can use them as follows:

var inputText = "afaUTE123567645gfhdDSFSD21312ASDFSAF21312sdafASasdfDF213asefd";
var pattern = @"[a-z][^a-z]|[A-Z][^A-Z]|[0-9][^0-9]";

var matches = Regex.Matches(inputText, pattern);

var indexes = matches
    .Select(m => m.Index + 1)
    .Prepend(0) // We also need beginning of the string to "cut" first part
    .Append(inputText.Length) // We also need end of the string to "cut" last part
    .ToArray();

var parts = new string[indexes.Length - 1];

for (int i = 1; i < indexes.Length; i++)
{
    var start = indexes[i - 1];
    var end = indexes[i];
    parts[i - 1] = inputText[start..end];
}

